# error while selecting row in a picker view iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker

i want to show picker view with years , i am storing year array in my userDC entitly class but i am getting an error on log message

```
   -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    userdc = [years objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"%d",userdc.user_year);


}
```

my error is like this

```
-[__NSCFString user_year]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaaa7220
```

Comment: What is NSLog of years?

Comment: nothing it gives me error nscfstring

Comment: what is the result of NSLog(@"%@",years);   ??

Comment: i set break point it gives me error on Nslog -[__NSCFString user_year]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaaa7220

Comment: are storing int or string in array??

Answer (score 1):

If your user_year is string then

```
NSLog(@"%@",userdc.user_year);
```

And if it is integer then

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",userdc.user_year]);
```

ANd if your userdc is dictionary then use

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[userdc objectForKey:@"user_year"]);
```

Comment: what is the output of NSLog(@"%@", userdc);

Answer (score 0):

yeppii .. i solved my own problem :):) by doing this, thanx all who helped me, cheers

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    userdc=[[userDC alloc]init];
    userdc.user_year = [years objectAtIndex:row];

    NSLog(@"%@",userdc.user_year);

}
```